# Scrapy Xpath to get text based on a tag with text in the container

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <strong>Ingredients:</strong> TOMATOES (TOMATOES AND FIRE ROASTED TOMATOES, TOMATO JUICE, CITRIC ACID, CALCIUM CHLORIDE), WHITE WINE VINEGAR, CARROTS. <span style="font-style:italic">Date Available</span>: 07/14/2017&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="font-style:italic">Date Last Updated by Company</span>: 07/14/2017
</div>
```

What I'm looking to extract is the list of ingredients using Scrapy with Xpath. The only identifying construct is a div that contains

```
<strong>Ingredients:</strong>
```

but I can't figure out how to extract the ingredients based on those rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text you're looking for can be identified as ***direct following sibling* of the `strong` element**, which translates to the following XPath expression :

```
query = "//div/strong[.='Ingredients:']/following-sibling::text()[1]"
```

without the predicate `[1]` the query would have returned 'date available' and 'date last updated' as well.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if helpful please try it.

```
response.xpath('//strong[.="Ingredients:"]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
```